# Throws wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Rails active record throws the following error.

```
 irb(main):030:0* Subscription.where(valid_until: nil).where.not(activated_on: nil)
    ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1+)
```

There are 5 nil entries for valid_until

```
irb(main):032:0> Subscription.where(valid_until: nil).count
2017-05-02 19:03:43.867 [MEH]  (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pti_subscriptions" WHERE "pti_subscriptions"."valid_until" IS NULL
=> 5
```

The problem is with where.not.  Any ideas?

Comment: What vresion of rails?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn            Rails 3.2.13

Comment: `where.not` was introduced much later, it's not available in Rails 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 4 where.not is introduced. You are working on Rails 3.2.13, so you have to do something like this:

```
 Subscription.where('valid_until IS NULL and activated_on IS NOT NULL')
```